# Project with a different file

Tags: ios, xcode, bounce

sorry I did not describe it knew about the problem in the title.

But I'm studying a project that I downloaded and my is identical over does not work, noting the project that he has downloaded a different file within the folder product that is at the root.

See the image file name is **SKBounceAnimationTests.octest** and has a folder in the project that looks like it has links to that file.

How do I get my project work?

In the picture is the original design.

[image]

Below is my project, see who has the file / Library SKBounceAnimationTests.octest
[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Can you clarify or describe it more?

Comment: I am a beginner, and I'm reflecting on this project, however I do not know SKBounceAnimationTests.octest add the file that seems to be another project within main project

Comment: whats the problem? hit CMD+R to compile and show the error message

Comment: I edited my post, placing the image of my project. there's no error but it does not have the expected result.

Comment: Here is the project that I mirrored: https://github.com/khanlou/SKBounceAnimation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Products* are the output of *Targets*.

In your original project, I can see there are two targets. The first target is the iOS app. The product for this target is `SKBounceAnimation.app`. The second target is the unit tests for the iOS app. The product for this target is `SKBounceAnimationTests.octest`.

In your new project, I can see there is only one target. That target is the iOS app. The product for this target is `bounce_animate.app`. You don't have a target for unit tests; therefore, you don't have a `.octest` product.

If you want to add in a unit test target, read [Setting Up Unit-Testing in a Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html) or do a web search for how to setup a unit test target.

---

**NOTE:** Unit tests are not mandatory, but are a useful part of any good software development process. If you aren't familiar with unit tests, you can do a web search on that too.